# VSCode: ctrl+space to get bower package version?

Tags: autocomplete, bower, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, with node modules and package.json, if I press ctrl+space in the version of a package, it will show me possible versions.

Is the same thing possible with bower packages found into bower.json file ? Right now, I can autocomplete package name with ctrl+space, but whenever I press ctrl+space over the version string, I get "no suggestions".

[image: no version is suggested]